# Freehand red circles

Tags: popularity-contest, image-processing

Over on http://meta.stackoverflow.com, we have a few memes of our own. One of them is Freehand Red Circles.

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/180276):

[image]

So, the challenge is,

### can you draw freehand red circles... with code?

Additional restrictions:

- You will take an **image** as input, and you must output the image with freehand red circle added.
- Must be predictable, i.e. same image input must result in same output. You can use randomness, but results have to be consistent for same input.
- Output must be exactly the same image as input, except with circle (no other alterations).
- The freehand red circle must look freehand (no perfect circles!), be red (obviously), and look generally like a circle (no random squiggly lines).

---

This is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), so the answer with the most upvotes at the beginning of March 2014 will win. There is no specific goal, other than "freehand red circles," so be as creative as possible so you get the most upvotes! (To be as unbiased as possible, I will upvote any answer that follows the rules.)

Comment: I think this needs a bit more clarification. Are we to a) draw a nothing but a circle on a plain white canvas, b) take an image containing text, and draw a circle around the text block, or c) take a text, and create an image of the text with a circle around it?

Comment: +1 to @primo. Also, there's other things to be considered: If all we need to do is draw a circle, is it the same circle every time or does the program need to be capable of drawing different circles - and are those circles to just be randomly different, or somehow specified by user input? Does the program need to be capable of handling user input at all, to determine the size or shape of the circle? Does it matter what format the image output is in, or could someone just come up with some clever ASCII art?

Comment: I think the answer is "this is a popularity contest, so impress your code-golf buddies"

Comment: I don't know what is unclear about this question. @Iszi - The key word is freehand. Open up Paint or GIMP and draw some freehand circles, do they all look the same? From the description and the link, it looks like you have to draw circles around something, which would imply X & Y and size. What does it matter what file format you use? Just run it through a converter if you want PNG, JPEG or whatever.

Comment: I believe with McKay.  If you want a lot of upvotes, draw random freehand circles.  Otherwise, hardcode your circle in.

Comment: @primo Any of them; it's your decision.

Comment: @primo Okay, I've updated the question to make it have a more concrete goal.

Comment: @Iszi (see above comments)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## C — about <s>750</s> 720 bytes if squeezed<sup>*</sup>

I think I came up with something that looks freehand-y enough.

- starts at a random angle
- draws a full circle plus or minus a bit
- uses a thick squiggly line (maybe *too* squiggly!)
- is customizable by changing a `MAGIC` number

Compile:

```
gcc -o freehand freehand.c -lm
```

Run:

```
./freehand [X center in % W] [Y center in % H] [radius in % diagonal] < [PPM file input] > [PPM file output]
```

Example:

```
./freehand 28.2 74.5 3.5 < screenshot.ppm > freehand.ppm
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAGIC      42
#define UNIFORM(x) ((x) * (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX)

typedef struct {unsigned char r, g, b;} RGB;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int W, H, i, f, g, x, y;
    double X, Y, R, a, r;
    RGB *p;

    srand(MAGIC);

    if (argc != 4 || scanf("P6 %d %d 255\n", &W, &H) != 2)
        return 1;

    p = malloc(sizeof(RGB) * W * H);

    fread(p, sizeof(RGB), W * H, stdin);

    X = W * atof(argv[1]) / 100.0;
    Y = H * atof(argv[2]) / 100.0;
    R = hypot(W, H) * atof(argv[3]) / 100.0;

    for (a = UNIFORM(M_PI), i = 2.0 * M_PI * R + UNIFORM(R / 4.0), r = R; i > 0; i--, a += 1.0 / R)
    {
        r += UNIFORM(2.0) - 1.0;
        f = sin(a) * r + X;
        g = cos(a) * r + Y;

        for (x = f - 2; x <= f + 2; x++)
        {
            for (y = g - 2; y <= g + 2; y++)
            {
                if (x >= 0 && x < W && y >= 0 && y < H)
                {
                    RGB *s = p + y * W + x;
                    s->r = 255;
                    s->g = 0;
                    s->b = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("P6 %d %d 255\n", W, H);
    fwrite(p, sizeof(RGB), W * H, stdout);

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

* and using `U` for `UNIFORM` and `M` for `MAGIC`

Answer (score 27):

## C + GD library

Instead of just drawing circles any old where, I thought it would be fun to find something red in the picture and draw a circle around that.

Here are some examples of the results obtained [with](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:V-Pick_Group.JPG) [a](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Botones.jpg) [few](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_line_of_colored_pushpins.jpg) [photos](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Grey_and_red_Mini%27s_-_Flickr_-_foshie.jpg) [from](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Post_box_-_geograph.org.uk_-_168995.jpg) [Wikimedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SEAT_600_cars.jpg) [Commons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Redbutton.jpg):

[image: red things with circles appearing around them]

And here's the code. It's a bit messy, but not too difficult to follow, I hope:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gd.h>

#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))

/* Used for image segmentation */
int floodfill(int *tmp, int i, int w, int id) {
  int np=1;
  tmp[i]=id;
  if (tmp[i-w-1]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i-w-1,w,id);
  if (tmp[i-w]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i-w,w,id);
  if (tmp[i-w+1]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i-w+1,w,id);
  if (tmp[i-1]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i-1,w,id);
  if (tmp[i+1]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i+1,w,id);
  if (tmp[i+w-1]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i+w-1,w,id);
  if (tmp[i+w]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i+w,w,id);
  if (tmp[i+w+1]<0) np+=floodfill(tmp,i+w+1,w,id);
  return np;
}

int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {
  FILE          *infile,*outfile;
  gdImagePtr    img;
  int           *t, *tmp;
  int           w,h,x,y,r,g,b;
  int           c,redness,rgb;
  int           i,np,max,min,thresh;
  int           xt,yt,n;
  int           areaID,size,maxID;
  double        xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax,rad,r0,th;
  gdPoint       v[33];

  
  /* Check command line and open source JPEG file */
  if (argv!=3) return printf("Usage: %s <in.jpg> <out.jpg>\n",argc[0]);
  if (!(infile=fopen(argc[1],"r"))) return printf("Can't open <%s>\n",argc[1]);
  if (!(img=gdImageCreateFromJpeg(infile))) return printf("Bad JPEG: <%s>\n",argc[1]);
  fclose(infile);
  
  /* Extract red pixels and auto-threshold */
  w=img->sx;
  h=img->sy;
  np=w*h;
  t=tmp=calloc(np,sizeof(int));
  for (max=0,min=255,y=1;y<h-1;y++) {
    for (x=1;x<w-1;x++) {
      rgb=gdImageGetTrueColorPixel(img,x,y);
      r = (rgb&0xff0000)>>16;
      g = (rgb&0xff00)>>8;
      b = rgb&0xff;
      redness = max(0,r-(max(g,b)+abs(g-b)));
      if (redness>max) max=redness;
      if (redness<min) min=redness;
      *t++ = redness;
    }
    t += 2;
  }
  thresh = (max+min)/2;
  for (t=tmp,i=0;i<np;i++,t++) *t=((*t>thresh)?-1:0);
  
  /* Label each area detected */
  areaID=1;
  maxID=0;
  max=-1;
  for (t=tmp,i=0;i<np;i++,t++) {
    if (*t<0) {
      size=floodfill(tmp,i,w,areaID);
      if (size>max) {
        max = size;
        maxID = areaID;
      }
      areaID++;
    }
  }
  
  /* Calculate centre coordinates and area */
  if (max>0) {
    xt=yt=n=xmax=ymax=0;
    xmin=w; ymin=h;
    for (t=tmp,y=0;y<h;y++) {
      for (x=0;x<w;x++) {
        if (*t++==maxID) {
          xt+=x;
          yt+=y;
          n++;
          if (x<xmin) xmin=x;
          if (y<ymin) ymin=y;
          if (x>xmax) xmax=x;
          if (y>ymax) ymax=y;
        }
      }
    }
    x = xt/(2*n) + (xmax+xmin)/4;
    y = yt/(2*n) + (ymax+ymin)/4;

    r0 = max(20,min(min(w,h),max(xmax-xmin,ymax-ymin))/2);
  }
  /* Default circle if nothing found */
  else {
    x=w/2; y=h/2; r0=min(w,h)/3;
  }
  
  /* Draw a red circle */
  for (th=4.0,i=0;i<33;i++) {
    rad = r0 * (1.2 + (" ,<MYZVSB>@EJIOSWZfgb^bbfgeZTOI@2"[i]-87)/160.0);
    v[i].x = x + rad * sin(th);
    v[i].y = y + rad * cos(th);
    th += 0.22;
  }
  gdImageSetThickness(img,7);
  c = gdImageColorAllocate(img,255,0,0);
  gdImageOpenPolygon(img,v,33,c);
  
  /* Output results to file */
  printf("Saving...\n");
  if (!(outfile=fopen(argc[2],"w"))) {
    return printf("Can't open <%s> for writing\n",argc[2]);
  }
  gdImageJpeg(img,outfile,85);
  fclose(outfile);
  gdImageDestroy(img);
  printf("Finished\n");
  return 0;
}
```

---

**Note:** Markdown messed up my link in the comments, so I'll just point out that the code uses [segmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) to identify *all* the areas of red in the picture, and then draws a circle around the largest of these. For example, [this image](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Buket_and_spade_on_Killahoey_Strand_-_geograph.org.uk_-_1426946.jpg):

[image: red bucket and spade on a beach]

produces the following output:

[image: the red bucket has a circle around it, because it is larger than the spade]

Comment: Nice job! ;) Goes more with the theme of drawing them to emphasize something. But I'm curious about what it would do if there were two red objects...? (+1)

Comment: It converts all the red areas into different segments and chooses the largest. So for example in [this photo of a red bucket and spade](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Buket_and_spade_on_Killahoey_Strand_-_geograph.org.uk_-_1426946.jpg), the bucket wins. [Here's the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EDx8k.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica

```
ClearAll[f]
f[image_,rad_, xPos_:.5,yPos_:.5,color_:Darker[Red,0.3],thick_:.01,axes_:False]:=
 Module[{i=ImageDimensions[image],rr,y=SeedRandom[2]},
 rr:=RandomReal[{-.1,.1}];
 Show[image,Graphics[{color,JoinForm["Round"],CapForm["Round"],Thickness[thick],
 Line[t=Table[{rad i[[2]] (Cos[z]+rr)+i[[1]]xPos,rad i[[2]] (Sin[z]+rr)+i[[2]] yPos},
 {z,0, 2 Pi+2Pi/12,Pi/12}]]}],Axes-> axes]]
```

`f` takes the following parameters:

- image: the image that will be marked up with a circle
- rad: the radius of the circle, in fraction of image width
- xPos: the position of the center of the circle along x, from 0 to 1 (default=.5)
- yPos: the position of the center of the circle along y, from 0 to 1 (default=.5)
- color: ink color (default= dark red)
- thickness: stroke thickness (default = .01)
- axes: whether to display axes (default = False)

---

**Examples**

```
text = Import["text.png"]
f[text,.13,.58,.23]
```

### [image: pic1]

A different radius, location, blue color, thicker stroke, displaying axes.

```
f[text,.22,.7,.5,Blue,.015,True]
```

[image: pic2]

Comment: Wow, very nice! Is this random, though? (It must produce same output for same input.)

Comment: I used randomness for the deviations from a true circle.  I thought that was ok.  If not, I can hardwire the shape.

Comment: "Must be predictable, i.e. same image input must result in same output. You can use randomness, but results have to be consistent for same input." There must be some way to get a seeded RNG in Mathematica, right?

Comment: Yes, `SeedRandom` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Alright, great! +1